# Customising @Cacheble in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

Is there any way that `@Cacheble` annotation can be customised to store only some specific fields of retuned object in Cache.

```
@Cacheble
public Person getPersonById(String personID);
```

I want to store personId and personName and all remaining fields should not be Cached.

How to achieve this? Or any other alternative approach to explore?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This may create problems if someone is calling this method and only gets a partial object

Comment: Weird use-case. Looks like [X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please share more details

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a jackson serializer in the RedisCacheManager.

```
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
      
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();

        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
        redisCacheConfiguration.serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer));
        RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder builder = RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory).cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

And jackson provides some ways to ignore fields such as `@JsonIgnore` so that you can achieve this.